# How to repeat field groups in TYPO3 extbase?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I would like to set up a "repeating field group" in an existing extbase/fluid extension quickly.

Instead of

```
Firstname ________
Lastname  ________
```

I'd like to achieve IRRE style behaviour with a `+`button, so editors can add more first and last name pairs (authors in that case) easily.

The extension is working already, and there is content present already.

Any chance this could be transformed easily?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve that:

1. Use AJAX: The click on the `+` button calls a "newPerson" action that returns a Fluid form with the firstName, lastName pair. Besides this form you have a button "save" that saves the person by AJAX and attaches it to your parent object.
2. Create the forms "manually" with field names like e.g. `name="tx_myext_myplugin[persons][new12345][firstName]"` and `name="tx_myext_myplugin[persons][new12345][lastName]"`. Where "new12345" contains a random number created on generating the fields so it is unique. Then you accept `$persons` in your createWhateverAction as an array. You iterate through the array and create a new object of type person for each entry and attach it to the parent object.

It mainly depends on your taste and if you need the built-in validation and/or property mapping of Extbase.

Comment: Can you point me to an example (can also be an existing extension) on how to implement those two ways? And: Which solution is the one with "built-in validation and/or property mapping of Extbase"?

Comment: I don't know a working example I could just point you to. I've implemented both, in one project the part is public (after login), in another not. Are you familiar with AJAX and Extbase, where should I start with samples?

Comment: With Extbase yes, I can build an extension and modify it afterwards, add VHs and change the controller. With AJAX & Extbase no, not at all

Comment: Probably the simplest solution would be to add the names as separate (IRRE) items as an 1:n relationship when designing the extension.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time yet to elaborate on the topic. Stay tuned, but with patience :-).